# Not able to register Broadcast receiver Dynamically 

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, onpause

I am registering my reciver in OnResume and unregistering in OnPause is Something is wrong with my code

```
package com.bd2;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.provider.Contacts.People;
import android.util.Log;

public class BroadcastReceiver2Activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
private int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID;
IntentFilter intentfilter;



  @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    intentfilter = new IntentFilter(); 
    intentfilter.addAction("android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE");


}

 @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onResume();
   /*intfilter = new IntentFilter();
      intfilter.addAction("android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE");*/
   registerReceiver(receiver, intentfilter);
   //       sendBroadcast();

  }

   @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);


    }

   private BroadcastReceiver receiver=new BroadcastReceiver(){


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
          Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"Time Reset!",System.currentTimeMillis());
          PendingIntent myIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, People.CONTENT_URI), 0);
          notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Time has been Reset", "Click on me to view Contacts", myIntent);
          notifyDetails.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
          mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
                Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"Sucessfully Changed Time");
    }

   }; 



   }
```

////////MANIFEST FILE

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.bd2"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".BroadcastReceiver2Activity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>



</application>
```

I am not getting my notification. If I'm doing this statically then it works

Comment: This is a very good question as no doubt others will run into this scenario later on. :) Dynamically registering broadcast receivers .. :D

Comment: @t0mm13b Dynamically registering broadcast receivers is easy, and Vicky is doing it right.  The issue is what I pointed out in my answer yesterday: you need to pause the activity (unregistering the receiver) in order to turn airplane mode on/off. Therefore you miss the broadcast. This is an example of a receiver that *should not* be registered dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit #3:**
Define global variable:

```
private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;
```

From the onCreate handler:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mIntentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE");
    mIntentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE");
    registerReceiver(receiver, mIntentfilter);
}
```

From the onResume handler:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onResume();
    // Be careful here... mIntentFilter might be gc'd! add checking to this!
   registerReceiver(receiver, mIntentFilter);
   Log.d(TAG, "onResume() - Registered!");
}
```

From the onPause handler:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   unregisterReceiver(receiver);
   Log.d(TAG, "onPause() - Unregistered!");
   super.onPause();
}
```

From the broadcast receiver:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver=new BroadcastReceiver(){
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED)){
           Log.d(TAG, "receiver/onReceive() - GOT THE INTENT!!!!");
        }else{
           Log.d(TAG, "receiver/onReceive() - NOPE! NO INTENT!");
        }
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
          Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"Time Reset!",System.currentTimeMillis());
          PendingIntent myIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, People.CONTENT_URI), 0);
          notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Time has been Reset", "Click on me to view Contacts", myIntent);
          notifyDetails.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
          mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
                Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"Sucessfully Changed Time");
    }

   };
```

At this point, remove the intent receiver (that I mentioned earlier) from the manifest as we're doing this programmatically. Also, define the permission!

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried create a class that contains the broadcast receiver instead of it being dynamically registered at runtime...?

Comment: ya i created it s working but i need it in this way dynamic way can u help!

Comment: Ok... try this. In your code above, I noticed you were unregistering the event *AFTER* calling `super.onPause();` Can you switch that around and see what happens, i.e. unregister first then call `super.onPause();` within the `onPause` handler?

Comment: Can you copy the logcat of the entire code running and put it into pastebin? *allow for about 5 seconds after exiting the app to ensure the logcat gets flushed in order to obtain the whole capture* :)

Comment: One thing - you're creating an intent filter once in the `onCreate`, When the activity gets paused/resumed, the intent filter, is it still there? (It could be garbage collected?) Look for the sake of not wasting time, scatter every path in the handlers with the logging to see where you're going wrong and check your logcat when doing so! :)

Comment: Also! It is good habit to do this in every class you declare and use - `private static final String TAG="myClass";` and when logging, use this `Log.d(TAG, "some_message goes here");`

Comment: Not working man and thanks for teaching me log wats wrong anything in manifest

Comment: Vicky: Last and final answer to this - please see the updated code in there :)

Comment: You might also change the check within the receiver broadcast, now, am getting muddled - is it Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED or android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE.... think I need to lie down :D

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good to me other than the fact that you can't turn airplane mode on or off without pausing your Activity, which unregisters your receiver.  By the time you get back to your Activity, resuming and re-registering, you've missed the broadcast.

I have no idea what your ultimate goal is here, but if you want your app to receive the airplane mode Intent, the best idea is to register in your manifest.  (Technically you can do it dynamically, but that would require doing the registration/unregistration somewhere more permanent than `onResume()`/`onPause()` which I don't think is really what you want.)

Comment: Hi Darshan i acheived it in staic but i want it to do it dynamically can u tell me what i should do

Comment: You can register in `onCreate()` and unregister in `onDestroy()`, and it will kind of work, except that your Activity could be destroyed at any time, at which point it will stop working.  That's a bad idea and you shouldn't do it.  If you want the system to actually instantiate your BroadcastReceiver without regard to whether your Activity happens to be running or not (which you almost certainly do), then you should declare your receiver in your Manifest.

Comment: What if i regsiter it in onCreate() and unregister it in onDestory() but in the onDestroy() method y cant i call super.onPause()

Comment: @Vicky I've explained why the airplane mode broadcast is one that really should be declared in the Manifest. I'm not at all clear what you're really trying to accomplish here: why are you insisting on doing it dynamically? Is this a homework assignment?